# Video player with complex subtitle/audio selection logic?

Tags: video

I'd like a video player or add-on for one which allows selection of subtitle and audio tracks using a customisable logic system which can choose an arbitrary combination of audio and subtitle streams based on which streams exist or what their numbered positions are. The default language priority system in MPC-HC isn't sufficient.

Comment: E.g: I watch English stuff, various non-English films, anime I want subtitles for (and to avoid any dubs), and stuff I want in English but has Russian as the default.

 1. If Japanese audio exists, enable Japanese audio and English subtitles
 2. Else, if first audio stream is Russian but English audio exists, use English audio, and use Forced English subtitles if they exist (otherwise none)
 3. Else, use first audio stream. If first audio stream is non-English, enable English subtitles, but if first audio stream is English just use Forced English subtitles if they exist (otherwise none)